# What does "I have no shame when it comes to ignorance" mean?

Tags: grammar, american-english, speech

Does it mean one chooses to be ignorant regardless of shame, or submit to shame while admitting ignorance?

**Interviewer:** Tell me about your first felony arrest?

**Candidate**: I have no shame when it comes to ignorance; what's a felony?

Comment: I do not know, but i think this requires context. One might just as well lose his shame at the sight of ignorance and shamelessly feel superior compared to the ignorant.

Comment: good point; updated.

Comment: Well that is quite a weird context. Does it happen to be archaic? It seems to just state that the candidate points out that he is not ashamed of not being educated/ having no knowledge of the word "felony" and thus just openly asks what "felony" means. It underlines a certain "honesty" in the character. BUT; The last statement depends on even more context.

Comment: It may be referencing Benjamin Franklin: 'Being ignorant is not so much a Shame, as being unwilling to learn'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means

> I am not embarrassed to say that I do not understand (or know the meaning of X).

In the example given, the Candidate is saying that she or he cannot answer the question until the questioner defines the term. This could be sincere, or it could be a hedge to avoid answering the question (or a setup to quibble about an uncomfortable answer).

Comment: I have no shame in seeking fame; please upvote my question, :-D

Comment: I have no shame in downvoting people who ask for upvotes.

Comment: @HotLicks ...sarcasm emphasized, hence the `:-D`, my apologies if such humor doesn't register with you.

Comment: @raffian - If I had taken you seriously I would have actually downvoted you.

Comment: @HotLicks my bad, it just wasn't obvious, though timing was suspect since someone _did_ downvote me, lol